# How to identify black or dark images in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

How to identify black/dark image in C#. Is there any API to check the image visibility or darkness ratio? In my application, while copying images, I want to check each image and want to discard black images.

Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: @dreamwalker You don't need to go around adding the .net tag to every single C# question.  That's not adding value to the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An idea to get the image darkness/brightness can be:

```
Bitmap bitmap = // the bitmap
var colors = new List<Color>();
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Size.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Size.Height; y++)
    {
        colors.Add(bitmap.GetPixel(x, y));
    }
}

float imageBrightness = colors.Average(color => color.GetBrightness());
```

Maybe consider dark images as ones with brightness less than 0.1 (or any other value relevant)

Comment: Bitmap.GetPixel is super slow. DreamWalker's solution of using BitMap.LockBits and unsafe code will outperform this by a long way...

Comment: As ParmesanCodice mentioned, I am now filtering slightly bigger images (640x480) and dark image filter makes it so slow.

Answer (score 7):

```
// For fast access to pixels        
public static unsafe byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) { 
    BitmapData bmd = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                     PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bmd.Height * bmd.Stride];
    byte* pnt = (byte*) bmd.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr) pnt, bytes, 0, bmd.Height * bmd.Stride);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmd);
    return bytes;
}

public bool IsDark(Bitmap bitmap, byte tolerance, double darkProcent) {
    byte[] bytes = BitmapToByteArray(bitmap);
    int count = 0, all = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 4) {
        byte r = bytes[i + 2], g = bytes[i + 1], b = bytes[i];
        byte brightness = (byte) Math.Round((0.299 * r + 0.5876 * g + 0.114 * b));
        if (brightness <= tolerance)
            count++;
    }
    return (1d * count / all) <= darkProcent;
}

public void Run(Bitmap bitmap) { // Example of use
    // some code
    bool dark = IsDark(bitmap, 40, 0.9); 
    // some code
}
```

Comment: +1, it may help some users to provide some explaining for the math on the brightness line.

Comment: I do not know too about the math of brightness..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [AForge.NJET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) framework which includes Image Processing support.
For example, see the [`ImageStatisticsHSL` Class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/16ee3168-882c-a0e9-eb00-e881cc81992a.htm). Choose a proper `Saturation` value, or use the `Luminance` histogram.

> The class is used to accumulate statistical values about images, like histogram, mean, standard deviation, etc. for each HSL color channel.
>
> The class accepts 24 and 32 bpp color images for processing.
>
> Sample usage C#:

```
// gather statistics
ImageStatisticsHSL stat = new ImageStatisticsHSL( image );
// get saturation channel's histogram
ContinuousHistogram saturation = stat.Saturation;
// check mean value of saturation channel
if ( saturation.Mean > 0.5 )
{
    // do further processing
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning Mean > 0.5? Is that 0.5 is threshold? if above 0.5 is fine if below it means black?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by iterating over all pixels in your image, computing the [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color of each pixel, and then averaging the 'V' component (which represents the 'brightness' of the color).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Elisha for the idea, I am doing it in this way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("123712.jpg");
float brightness = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Size.Width; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Size.Height; y++)
     {
          brightness += bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
     }
}

float average = brightness / (bitmap.Size.Width * bitmap.Size.Height);
```

Comment: euhm, That last line is wrong? should be bitmap.Size.Width * bitmap.Size.Height

Comment: yeah, I was wrong! I didn't realize this. Thats why I was thinking that why the average is too big. Thank you for correction :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Accord.Net Imaging for better performance. GetPixel is rather slow.

Mind the needed using statements:

```
using Accord.Imaging;

using Accord.Imaging.Converters;


    private bool IsDarkImage(Bitmap aBitmap, int darkThreshold)
    {
        double arrayAverage = 0;
        bool isDark = true;

        ImageToArray conv = new ImageToArray(min: 0, max: 255);
        conv.Convert(aBitmap, out double[] array);
        arrayAverage = (double) array.Sum() / (double) array.Length;
        if (arrayAverage < darkThreshold)
        {
            isDark = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isDark = false;
        }
        return isDark;
    }
```